# How to have Acces level Control the easiest way?

Tags: php, laravel

I am designing a CMS and i have setup users based on the role.How do i limit the users of their permissions based on their access level?

Comment: It's all up to you, however you can add role_permissions table.

Comment: I would recommend use spatie/laravel-permission... 
https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: There are many libraries that will handle this for you. Just do some research and use one you like. No need to reinvent the wheel. If you still want to build it yourself, there are many guides/examples out there. Currently, the question is too unspecific and broad.

Comment: Thank you.I have searched content and tried out some.Some did not work properly.Thank you for your assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to get users by their role. Have a column for your users table called role or whatever you name it.

You can do Access Level Control  easily with [Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization)

In your `app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` register your policy. Example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;

public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {

        $this->registerPolicies($gate);

        $gate->define('isUser', function($user){
          return $user->role == 'user';
        });

        $gate->define('isDealer', function($user){
          return $user->role == 'dealer';
        });
    }
```

`isUser , isDealer` are the user Types we are defining to Use in the project blade,controllers.You can change it as you like.Role is the column that you created in the table and we are comparing with the table values which are the user types `user` and `dealer`.

you can limit values in blade with laravel method

```
@can('isUser')
<only visible to users based on role user>
@endcan
```

It will be still accessible via routes so you can limit via controller functions or routes.

```
//controller
public function create()
{
   if(!Gate::allows('isUser')){  // || for multiple parameters  can('isAdmin' || 'isUser)
            abort(404,"Abort");
   }
   return view('yourView');
}
```

This way the controller function will be **not** accessible for the roles defined. 
Check the official documentation for in detail methods and information.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Gate' not found

Comment: ```use Gate;``` in controller.