# Admin & User for newbie

Tags: laravel, admin

I would like to separate 2 types of users. The Admin and the user basic.
The Admin can create several recordings except the user basic which can only see.

[image]

Here, the user `Admin` adds a recording

My second user can just see the recordings but I don't know how to do this?

[image]

My questions:

1) I must to create a field in my table "students" ?

I have for now this:

// students

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->bigIncrements('id');
         $table->string('name');
         $table->string('firstname');
         $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

// users

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My 2 models:

// Student

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected  $fillable = ['name', 'firstname'];


}
```

// User

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

2) I must to create a class Admin?

Comment: I think you need to know about RBAC concept

Comment: The way i understood the question, you need access level control.You may use use a table field called role to store the user role and use the gate logic. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54664162/7964905

Comment: I agree with Mateus, but if you are looking to make it as simple as you say here then you can add an "is_admin" field to the user table. Then in your blade template you can check Auth::user()->is_admin before displaying your buttons or taking any actions in your controllers.

Comment: Yes, it also works. But i think it's better to use a permission based access control, since with it is easy to add more type of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [laravel guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards) or something like a package to control the user access inside your application. [This one](https://github.com/jungessolutions/laravel-acl) can help you to do this.

Basically, what you need is it:

Create a `permissions` table:

```sh
php artisan make:model Permission -m
```

Here is how your table should look like:

```
|---permissions---|
|       id        |
|      slug       |
|   description   |  
|     name        |
|-----------------|
```

Then, create a `user_has_permissions` table:

```sh
php artisan make:migration create_user_has_permissions_table
```

This table should looks like this:

```
|---user_has_permissions---|
|         user_id          |
|      permission_id       |
|--------------------------|
```

The second table store the user permissions.

Add a relationship to your user model:

```php
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'user_has_permissions');
}
```

The function above return all user permissions.

Add another function, to check if the user has some permissions:

```php
public function hasPermission($permissionSlug)
{
    return (bool)$this->permissions()->where('slug', $permissionSlug)->count();
}
```

If the user has some permission, the `hasPermission` return `true`. Otherwise, returns `false`.

Now, you can use the [laravel gates and policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#gates) to control the access for some areas of your app:

First, create a policy to use with your gate:

```sh
php artisan make:policy VerifyUserPermissionPolicy
```

This policy will be placed into `app/Policies` directory.

Add two methods to your new policy:

```php
public function onlyViewRecords(User $user)
{
    return $user->hasPermission('only-view-records');
}

//And this one:
public function admin(User $user)
{
    return $user->hasPermission('admin');
}
```

> Dont forget to add the `admin` and `only-view-records` permissions to your permissions table;

Within your `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider` file, add this lines within the boot method:

```php
Gate::define('admin', '\App\Policies\VerifyUserPermissionPolicy@admin');
Gate::define('only-view-records', '\App\Policies\VerifyUserPermissionPolicy@onlyViewRecords');
```

Now, you can check for user permissions using the [laravel can](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-the-user-model) method:

```php
if ($user->can('admin')) {
    //What an admin can do?
}

if ($user->can('only-view-records') {
    //What this type of user can do?
}
```

Or, if you prefer, use `gate`:

```php
if (Gate::allows('admin')) {
   //The user can execute admin actions
}


if (Gate::allows('only-view-records')) {
    //This user can only view some recors
}
```

Again, if you [check this package](https://github.com/jungessolutions/laravel-acl), this will be so much easier.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Mateus. ^^

Comment: Glad that i can help you :)